# Why is 'lève-toi' when positive but 'ne te lève pas' when negative?

Tags: expressions, pronoms, négation, impératif

It is *lève-toi* when positive, but *ne te lève pas* when negative.

Why does the pronoun itself and its position change? Is this an inconsistency? What does native speakers think about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "irregular" form is the positive imperative which uses the stressed pronoun *toi* after the verb.

> *Lève-toi !*

All other French tenses use the unstressed reflexive pronoun *te*:

> *Tu te lèves*
> *Tu ne te lèves pas*
> *Tu t'es levé*
> *Ne te lève pas !*
> ...

It's a pattern among romance languages imperatives:

> Spanish: *¡Levanta**te**!*   / *¡No **te** levanta!*
> Italian: *Alza**ti**!* / * *Non **ti** alzare!* (but also *Non alzarti*)
> Catalan: *Aixeca'**t**!*  / *No **t**’aixequis!*
> Romanian: *Ridică-**te**!* / *Nu **te** ridica!*

In spoken French, *ne* is often dropped leading to:

> *Te lève pas !*

A more radical evolution builds the negative imperative from the positive :

> Lève-toi pas !

This last form is probably not in your French grammar book, though.

Comment: Thank you. So is this an inconsistency in your opinion? Also have you ever heard some native speaker using *Lève-toi pas* ? What about *Ne lève-toi pas* ?

Comment: As a native speaker, I don't feel it like an inconsistency. It's just the way it is and has always been... I have heard people saying *Lève-toi pas !* but only in informal situations, or kids. I don't think I would ever say *lève-toi pas !* however, I sometimes says *Prends-le pas !* instead of *Ne le prends pas !*

Comment: *Ne lève-toi pas* is "impossible".